# Descriptions on Hover

Tags: jquery, dynamic, hover

```
<form action="">
    <input type="text" value="" class="card-num" />
    <input type="text" value="" class="card-cvv2"/>
</form>

<div class="description">
    <p class="card-num">Enter your 16 digit card number</p>
    <p class="card-cvv2">Enter the 3 digit number at the back of your card</p>
</div>
```

All descriptions are hidden initially. But when hovered on an element that has a matching

tag, display description?

I'd really appreciate any help.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fade in and out, or other effect you need, use .show() and .hide() for a simple no effects presentation.

```
   var thisClass; 
     $('input').hover(
          function () {
            thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
            $('description.'+thisClass).fadeIn(100)
          }, 
          function () {
            $('description.'+thisClass).fadeOut(100);
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {

    $('div.description p').hide();
          $('input').hover(
        function() {
            var matchingExplanationClass = $(this).attr('class');
            $('p.'+matchingExplanationClass).toggle();
        }
    );
  }
  );
```

Demo at jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ecosu3/2

Comment: Just one thing, what if the hovered element is not fixed, lets say it can be input or select or checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Set up handlers for "mouseover" and "mouseout" on the `<input>` tags that show only the `<p>` with matching class.

```
$('form input').mouseover(function() {
  $('div.description p').hide();
  $('div.description p.' + this.className).show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $('div.description p').hide();
});
```

(Not tested, but it's probably close.)

Comment: ...somehow I always forget the inbuilt `className` and go with `...attr('class')` *sigh* =/